# How to maintain different timestamps while making a union of two spark data frames?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp, union

I am trying to union two spark data frames with different timestamp values, but I am not able to get separate timestamps. I am getting a single timestamp for all the data, e.g.,

in **dataframe1 it is 2022-07-8T05:08:22.395+000**
in **dataframe2 it is 2022-07-8T05:02:10.757+000**,
but in **output it is 2022-07-8T05:08:34.651+000**
but I am **expecting timestamp from dataframe1 and dataframe2**.

Any specific reason for this and how I can prevent this?

I use Spark 3.1.2.

Using the following function:

```py
def unionMissing(df1, df2=hist_df):

    # Add missing columns to df1
    left_df = df1
    for column in set(df2.columns) - set(df1.columns):
        left_df = left_df.withColumn(column, F.lit(None))

    # Add missing columns to df2
    right_df = df2
    for column in set(df1.columns) - set(df2.columns):
        right_df = right_df.withColumn(column, F.lit(None))

    # Make sure columns are ordered the same
    return left_df.unionAll(right_df.select(left_df.columns))
```

I have also tried the following, but results were the same.

```py
df = df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True)
```

dataframe1:
[image: 2]

dataframe2:
[image: 3]

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: At some point, are you creating the timestamp yourself using a function like `F.current_timestamp()`?

Comment: yes, consider I want to maintain history table where I can see precise runtime for every instance but in future my column count may vary  but timestamp will be there for observation, So is it because of  F.current_timestamp() ?

Comment: Would it be possible to add to the question `df.explain()` of the output df?

Comment: sure, `Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.api.python.PythonSQLUtils.explainString.`got this while trying `df.explain()`

Comment: I am experimenting on organizational clusters may they disable `df.explain()`
do you think it if because `F.current_timestamp()` is there any way to avoid

Comment: Try to debug `current_timestamp`. I suspect that somewhere you override all the values in the df. So that later you don't get any of previous timestamps.

Comment: @JeevanKande if you're still experimenting, can you try using python's `datetime` module for the current timestamp? so, instead of `current_timestamp()`, you'll need to use `lit(datetime.datetime.now())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the situation is because of spark's [lazy evaluation](https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-lazy-evaluation/). Here's a test where I was able to replicate your issue and a way to solve it using python's `datetime` module.

```
data1_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1, 1)]).toDF(['id1', 'id2']). \
    withColumn('spark_currts', func.current_timestamp()). \
    withColumn('dttm_currts', func.lit(datetime.datetime.now()))

data1_sdf.show(truncate=False)

# +---+---+-----------------------+------------------------+
# |id1|id2|spark_currts           |dttm_currts             |
# +---+---+-----------------------+------------------------+
# |1  |1  |2022-07-11 10:42:00.346|2022-07-11 10:41:44.6466|
# +---+---+-----------------------+------------------------+

data2_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(2, 2)]).toDF(['id1', 'id3']). \
    withColumn('spark_currts', func.current_timestamp()). \
    withColumn('dttm_currts', func.lit(datetime.datetime.now()))

data2_sdf.show(truncate=False)

# +---+---+-----------------------+--------------------------+
# |id1|id3|spark_currts           |dttm_currts               |
# +---+---+-----------------------+--------------------------+
# |2  |2  |2022-07-11 10:42:30.703|2022-07-11 10:41:45.162876|
# +---+---+-----------------------+--------------------------+

data1_sdf.unionByName(data2_sdf, allowMissingColumns=True).show(truncate=False)

# +---+----+-----------------------+--------------------------+----+
# |id1|id2 |spark_currts           |dttm_currts               |id3 |
# +---+----+-----------------------+--------------------------+----+
# |1  |1   |2022-07-11 10:43:35.629|2022-07-11 10:41:44.6466  |null|
# |2  |null|2022-07-11 10:43:35.629|2022-07-11 10:41:45.162876|2   |
# +---+----+-----------------------+--------------------------+----+
```

Using current time from `datetime` module is retains the timestamp after the evaluation.